# Python MultiThreading. Releasing resources

Tags: python, multithreading, resources

I am writing super awesome software where i will create a new thread every new minute. This thread will store some data on a remote database server and end. When a new thread is created resources(memory...) are assigned to that thread. If i don't correctly free those resources at some time i will have a problem.

The thread that stores the data can sometimes end unexpectedly,  an error because the remote server is unreachable. This is not a problem the thread will end and the data will be stored the next minute together with the data of that next minute.

So my question is: Do python threads free all the resources they use when they end as expected? Do they free all resources when they end because of a error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python threads (as opposed to multiprocessing processes) use the same block of memory.  If a thread adds something to a data structure that is directly or indirectly referenced from the master thread or other workers (for instance, a shared dictionary or list), that data won't be deleted when the thread dies.  So basically, as long as the only data your threads write to memory is referenced by variables local to the thread target function scope or below, the resources should be cleaned up the next time the gc runs after the thread exits.